# java if statement to check if object is empty

Tags: java, jsp

hi I am new to java and I am creating a jsp and I am using scriplet code. I would like to be able to have my object to not display on the screen when it is empty.

```
<% if (webApp.getInfo != null) { %> <h6><%=webApp.getInfo()%> <% } %>
```

Currently it is checking if the object is null but it is still displaying a line on the page when I run the JSP. How can I check to see if webApp.getInfo is empty and not have a line display or test display for those headers?

Comment: Are you talking about the empty line in the HTML source? Those are usually not displayed in the final render, unless it's inside a `<pre>` or something.

Comment: If you don't want a blank in your HTML, don't put this expression on a line by itself.

Comment: its the h6 tag that is causing the space. So he needs to check for the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:if test="${!empty str}">
   <h6>...</h6>
</c:if>
```

Note that:

- this is meaningful only for strings, not for any object
- this is JSTL, which is preferred to scriptlets (from your example)
- your objects needs to be set as request attribute.
- you only need this if you have additional tags inside the if-clause. If it is only the string that you want to output, there is no need to check - as BalusC noted this is not displayed.
- you can trim whitepsaces from the jsp output using configurations provided by your servlet container, or if using servlet 3.0 - via `<trim-directive-whitespaces>` in web.xml